# Cannot reference template element inside directive

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a custom directive to use in Ionic framework.
My problem is during the linking phase, I'm not able to query inside my template.

My template is the following:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
<div class="searchBar">
    <div class="searchTxt">
        <div class="bgdiv"></div>
        <div class="bgtxt">
            <input class="searchBox" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <i class="searchIcon icon placeholder-icon" ng-click="callSearch()"></i>
</div>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

My linking function is

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){...}
```

But when I check the `element` the value is:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right" class="hide"></ion-nav-buttons>
```

How could I get the rest of the elements?
Is because I'm using another directive?
How can I address this?

Comment: Is like that the <ion-nav-buttons> is not compile and not traverse down.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the element, then you can make queries to the inside elements with the usuan JQuery syntax:

```
$(element).find('.searchBar')[0]
```

or

```
$(element).find('.searchBox')[0]
```